# tensorboard images are not getting updated

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I have the following code for my reinforcement learning program:

```
tbCallBack = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = log_dir,
        histogram_freq = 1, update_freq = 'epoch', write_graph = True, write_images = True)
```

The model fits data soon after getting data for training:

```
        model.fit(x = np.vstack(x_train),
                y = np.vstack(y_train),
                callbacks = [tbCallBack],
                verbose = 1, sample_weight = s_t)
```

I see my SCALARS, DISTRIBUTIONS, and HISTOGRAMS all getting updated but not the IMAGES in the tensorboard...
I see only one image, but no updates....Can you please let me know where the problem is ?
Here is the version information:

```
tensorboard               2.3.0              pyh4dce500_0  
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0  
keras                     2.4.3                         0  
keras-base                2.4.3                      py_0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my answer will help, but as far as my experience is concerned,
Tensorboard doesn't seem to update images well when using Windows, regardeless of the web browser being used.
Such issue seems to exist even in the latest version (2.6.0) of Tensorboard and latest version (2.6.0) of Tensorflow.

Please check the OS upon which you are running your reinforcement learning model. If you were using Windows, I suggest you port the Python code to Linux-based OSes like Ubuntu.

Comment: Just in case, I have written a post mentioning about this issue at the official github repo of Tensorboard -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/5293 -- If you have time, please check it out and see if there are any progress made to fix this issue.